# Implement Comparator for primitive boolean type?

Tags: java, comparator, primitive-types

I need some classes `implements Comparator`, and for one I want to compare primitive `boolean` (not `Boolean`) values.

IF it was a **B**oolean, I would just `return boolA.compareTo(boolB);` which would return 0, -1 or 1. But how can I do this with primitives?

Comment: have you heard of autoboxing?

Comment: @stackmonster There is a slight performance hit for autoboxing, so OP may still prefer to write the raw code.

Comment: Comparator doesnt take primitive types.  That was the question.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik As every possible `boolean` as an object is cached, auto-boxing may not cost as much as you expect.  Note: Every possible `byte` is also cached.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, I took that into account. The hit is really slight (one must dereference the `Boolean` constant) and is probably not worth the extra code.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can look up how it is implemented for the [`java.lang.Boolean`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Boolean.java#257), since that class, naturally, uses a primitive boolean as well:

```
public int compareTo(Boolean b) {
    return (b.value == value ? 0 : (value ? 1 : -1));
}
```

As of Java 7 you can simply use the built-in static method [`Boolean.compare(a, b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#compare(boolean,%20boolean)).

Comment: or you can just simply use Boolean.valueof(boolean).

Comment: Did you have in mind `Boolean.valueOf(a).compareTo(Boolean.valueOf(b))`? That's quite a mouthful, and slower than using `Boolean.compare(a, b)`.

Answer (score 13):

Since Java 7, the logic that [Marko Topolnik showed in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13229624/627727) has moved into another method to expose a way to compare primitive `boolean`.

[Javadoc for `Boolean.compare(boolean x, boolean y)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#compare%28boolean,%20boolean%29):

```
public static int compare(boolean x, boolean y)

Compares two boolean values. The value returned is identical to 
what would be returned by:

    Boolean.valueOf(x).compareTo(Boolean.valueOf(y))
```

Comment: So to sum up, even the JDK is doing it via autoboxing now (as of 7).

Comment: @PriiduNeemre: no it is not. Souce code is like this (at least in Java 8): public static int compare(boolean x, boolean y) {
        return (x == y) ? 0 : (x ? 1 : -1);
    }

Comment: @PriiduNeemre Yeah, Wim Deblauwe is correct. The Javadoc states that it is *identical* to the result if you compared them as objects. If you look at [Marko Topolnik's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229592/implement-comparator-for-primitive-boolean-type/13229624#13229624) and the source code in the Oracle JDK, you will see that the Oracle implementation is the same are the same.

Answer (score 5):

An even better approach and correct use of Boolean-Adapter class

```
public int compare(boolean lhs, boolean rhs) {
    return Boolean.compare(lhs, rhs);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Hint: This sorts the "false" values first. If you want to invert the sorting use:

```
(-1 * Boolean.compare(lhs, rhs))
```

Comment: or you can simply do this `Boolean.compare(rhs, lhs)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use java's autoboxing feature to alleviate this problem. You can read about autoboxing here: [Java autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two primitive boolean values b1 and b2 in following way.

(Boolean.valueOf(b1).equals(Boolean.valueOf(b2))